# Google Distance matrix for work is giving me invalid request when signing request with clientId and crypto key

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to obtain distance between two locations using Google Distance matrix API. I am using a signature as well to sign my request to Google.

Here is my request URI:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=driving&departure_time=1435234502&client=my-client-id&signature=my-obtained-signature.

I am using epochtime in UTC to send the request as mentioned in Google API documentation. But I am getting a response as mentioned below:

```
{ 
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "origin_addresses" : [], 
   "rows" : [], 
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST" 
}
```

---

Comment: Does the request succeed when using `now` as the `departure_time`?

Comment: yes the request succeeded but i am not sure whether the API was considering it.

Answer (score 1):

You need an API KEY to call Google Map Services

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?hl=En